# $(x+y)^a \geq x^a + y^a$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Take $x,y \in (0,\infty), a \in (1, \infty)$. For $a \in \mathbb N $ by binomial theorem it holds $$(x+y)^a \geq x^a + y^a.$$
Trying with some numbers it seems true also for $a \in (1, \infty)$. How can I prove it?

Comment: You mean, you want to know how to show it for all real $a \in (1, \infty)$?  Not just natural numbers?

Comment: You can use the fact that $x^\alpha$ is convex for $\alpha > 1$.  Or is that the fact you want to prove?

Comment: Thanks Daniel Fisher, also very nice comment/answer in the other question!

Answer (score 3):

Assume $y<x$. Then we have

$(x+y)^\alpha = x^\alpha(1+\frac{y}{x})^\alpha > x^\alpha (1+\frac{y}{x})$.

Last inequality since $(1+\frac{y}{x})>1$. But now $\frac{y}{x}<1$, hence $\frac{y}{x} > (\frac{y}{x})^\alpha$, thus

$x^\alpha (1+\frac{y}{x}) > x^\alpha (1+(\frac{y}{x})^\alpha) = x^\alpha+y^\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u,v\in(0,1)$ be such that $u+v=1$. Then with $a>1$, we have $u^a<u$ (to prove, for example, you can take $\log$: $u^a<u\iff a\log u<\log u\iff(a-1)\log u<0$) and $v^a<v$. And so
$$
u^a+v^a<u+v=1.
$$
Now, let $u=x/(x+y)$ and $v=y/(x+y)$.